# Dynamic import of json files does not work with Vite and VueJS after build

Tags: vue.js, import, vite

I'm using vueI18n for the internationalization of my app and I would like to load some translation files, only under certain conditions.

```
├── typescript@5.2.2
├── vite@4.4.9
├── vue-i18n@9.4.1
├── vue-tsc@1.8.13
└── vue@3.3.4
```

I tried with a dynamic import:

```js
// main.ts
let extraLocales;
if (import.meta.env.VITE_MY_VAR) {
  extraLocales = await import(`./locales/${import.meta.env.VITE_MY_VAR}/de.json`);
}
import deDefault from "./locales/de.json";

const i18n = createI18n({
  locale: "de",
  legacy: false,
  messages: {
    de: merge({}, deDefault, extraLocales ? extraLocales : {})
  }
});
```

In dev mode, with `npm run dev`, everything is fine and I can see a request to get the file `http://localhost:5173/src/locales/my_var_value/de.json?import=`.
But after building the app and serving it in a docker container with nginx, I get the following errors:

```
Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.
```

and

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to fetch dynamically imported module: http://localhost:8082/assets/locales/my_var_value/de.json
```

I already had to add this extra config, what I found not that great already:

```js
// vite.config.ts
    esbuild: {
      supported: {
        'top-level-await': true //browsers can handle top-level-await features
      },
    },
```

Any idea of what I'm doing wrong or maybe a suggestion how I could handle this?

Answer (score 0):

ok, in fact I already had the solution but missed the fact that I was using a promise and that the files were loaded after the instance of i18n was created

```
// main.ts

if (import.meta.env.VITE_MY_VAR) {
  const modules = import.meta.glob('./locales/*/de.json')
  for (const path in modules) {
    if (path.indexOf(import.meta.env.VITE_MY_VAR) > 0) {
      const mod:any = await modules[path]()
      extraLocales = mod.default;
    }  
  }
}
```

this did the trick. Still is this a good approach?